# clauses within clauses

Tags: grammar, syntax, て-form

Recently I was reading「鶴の笛」by (林芙美子) and came across this sentence:

> 若木の林のなかは、ところまだらに陽の光が煙っていて美しい景色でした。

Am I correct in assuming that this would be read as two clauses joined with the conjunctive form verb? As In:

> 若木の林のなかは美しいでした= clause 1

> ところまだらに陽の光が煙って= clause 2

Where clause 2 is inside clause 1?

Or would it be read where clause 2 is a clausal predicate that describes a component of clause 1 in some way? In which case, what is it describing and why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the 2nd reading. I guess any reading won't particularly affect the meaning of the sentence, so the 1st reading is fine.

Comment: There is no nesting in this sentence. This is essentially a [compound sentence](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/compound-sentence-examples.html) joined using a te-form. The two predicates are placed in parallel rather than in a parent-children relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply the following two sentences combined into one with 若木の林のなか kept as a common topic.

> 1. 若木の林のなかは、ところまだらに陽の光が煙っていました。
> 2. 若木の林のなかは、美しい景色でした。

Since the first describes what the speaker observed and the second what they thought, the first could be understood as indicating a reason for why the speaker thought the second was true.